# How to limit my regex that is detecting too much?

Tags: regex

I have a regex that is attempting to detect title & link markup:

```
[title](http://link.com)
```

So far I have:

```
(\[)(.*?)(\])(\(((http[s]?)|ftp):\/\/)(.*?)(\))
```

Which is detecting to much when an untitled link markup is before it

```
[http://google.com] [Digg](http://digg.com)
[Internal Page] Random other text [Digg](http://digg.com)
```

How can I limit the regex to just the titled link?

Full PHP for titled & untitled links:

```
    // Titled Links
    // [Digg](http://digg.com)
    // [Google](http://google.com)
    $text = preg_replace_callback(
        '/(\[)(.*?)(\])(\(((http[s]?)|ftp):\/\/)(.*?)(\))/',
        function ($match) {
            $link = trim($match[7]);
            $ret = "<a target='_blank' href='" . strtolower($match[5]) . "://" . $link . "'>" . trim($match[2]) . "</a>";
            if (strtolower($match[5]) == "http") {
                $ret .= "<img src='/images/link_http.png' class='link' />";
            } else if (strtolower($match[5]) == "https") {
                $ret .= "<img src='/images/link_https.png' class='link' />";
            } else if (strtolower($match[5]) == "ftp") {
                $ret .= "<img src='/images/link_ftp.png' class='link' />";
            }
            return $ret;
        },
        $text
    );

    // Untitled Links
    // [Internal Page]
    // [http://google.com]
    $text = preg_replace_callback(
        '/(\[)(.*?)(\])/',
        function ($match) {
            $link = trim($match[2]);

            $ret = "";
            if ($this->startsWith(strtolower($link), "https")) {
                $ret = "<a target='_blank' href='" . $link . "'>" . $link . "</a>";
                $ret .= "<img src='/images/link_https.png' class='link' />";
            } else if ($this->startsWith(strtolower($link), "http")) {
                $ret = "<a target='_blank' href='" . $link . "'>" . $link . "</a>";
                $ret .= "<img src='/images/link_http.png' class='link' />";
            } else if ($this->startsWith(strtolower($link),  "ftp")) {
                $ret = "<a target='_blank' href='" . $link . "'>" . $link . "</a>";
                $ret .= "<img src='/images/link_ftp.png' class='link' />";
            } else {
                $link = str_replace(" ", "_", $link);
                $ret = "<a href='" . $link . "'>" . trim($match[2]) . "</a>";
            }
            return $ret;
        },
        $text
    );
```

Comment: So much parentheses ... Anyways [here](http://regex101.com/r/hG9hM8)'s what I came up with, happy coding ...

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to go through Markdown links, you'll probably want to grab the regex and logic straight from the source:

https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown/blob/lib/Michelf/Markdown.php#L510

https://github.com/tanakahisateru/js-markdown-extra/blob/master/js-markdown-extra.js#L630

Answer (score 0):

Make the title optional by appending a '?' to the group that matches the title.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `(.*?)` try matching on something you really don't want, like a space e.g. `([^\s]+)`.

Also, the whole of the second part is optional (if you can have a untitled link), so add the `?` as @Arnout suggests, e.g.

```
(\(((http[s]?)|ftp):\/\/)([^\s]+)(\))?
```

May I also suggest, (though I'm not sure it's supported in PHP regex [it appears to be](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), using the whitespace flag and breaking it up over a few lines for readability:

```
/
  (
    \[
  )
  (.*?)
  (
    \]
  )
  (
    \(
     (
       (http[s]?)
         |
       ftp
     )
     :\/\/
  )
  (.*?)
  (
    \)
  )
/x
```

That is a lot clearer, and it's easier to see:

- The `[s]?` could just be `s?`
- The scheme brackets should be ((?:https?)|(?:ftp)) or it only ORs on the `f`, and you get additional unneeded captures.

You may possibly be able to comment on it too, within the regex (again, I'm unsure you can with PHP).

Answer (score 0):

This works but doesn't have the parentheses for all the groups you're trying to match.

```
\[[\w\s]+\]\((https?|ftp)://[^)]+\)
```